# flutter) How do I make arrow lines with canvas?

Tags: flutter, canvas

I want to put an arrow at the end (or on both sides) of a line drawn with a drawLine() of canvas.

Like this

[image]

Can I know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's actually not that hard to do - there's just a little math involved.

Let's have a line and paint set up like this:

```
final paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.black
  ..strokeWidth = 2;

final p1 = Offset(50, 50);
final p2 = Offset(250, 150);

canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
```

this will give us:

[image]

Now if we think of this line as a vector, we remember a vector has a direction. To get the direction we must find the angle between the start and the end of the line. This can be done using the `atan2` function of dart's math library.

So import the math library

`import 'dart:math' as math;`

and add the following lines

```
final dX = p2.dx - p1.dx;
final dY = p2.dy - p1.dy;
final angle = math.atan2(dY, dX);
```

Afterwards let's determine a size and an angle for the arrow we're about to put at the end of the line:

```
final arrowSize = 15;
final arrowAngle=  25 * math.pi / 180;
```

Everything that's left is actually drawing the arrow. This is basically done by drawing a triangle at the proper angle the line is facing using a path.

```
final path = Path();

path.moveTo(p2.dx - arrowSize * math.cos(angle - arrowAngle),
    p2.dy - arrowSize * math.sin(angle - arrowAngle));
path.lineTo(p2.dx, p2.dy);
path.lineTo(p2.dx - arrowSize * math.cos(angle + arrowAngle),
    p2.dy - arrowSize * math.sin(angle + arrowAngle));
path.close();
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Which will finally give us:

[image]

Comment: Really nice solution. However at the top of the arrow the line is sticking out. Wrap an interactive viewer around the widget and see for yourself

Comment: I suggest you to substract ``arrowSize - 2`` (2 being the strokewidth) from ``p2`` when drawing the line. so it only draws until the triangle starts

Comment: Just tried it out and got a sticky pointy arrow *muhahahah*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution derived from obscure's answer to subtract the head of the arrow from the line so it does not stick out:

```dart
  void drawArrow(Offset a, Offset b, Canvas canvas, Color color) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = 2
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    const arrowSize = 10;
    const arrowAngle = pi / 6;

    final dX = b.dx - a.dx;
    final dY = b.dy - a.dy;
    final angle = atan2(dY, dX);

    // Recalculate b such that it's the end of the line minus the arrow.
    final Offset subtractedB = Offset(
      b.dx - (arrowSize - 2) * cos(angle),
      b.dy - (arrowSize - 2) * sin(angle),
    );

    canvas.drawLine(a, subtractedB, paint);
    final path = Path();

    path.moveTo(b.dx - arrowSize * cos(angle - arrowAngle),
        b.dy - arrowSize * sin(angle - arrowAngle));
    path.lineTo(b.dx, b.dy);
    path.lineTo(b.dx - arrowSize * cos(angle + arrowAngle),
        b.dy - arrowSize * sin(angle + arrowAngle));
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
class ArrowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    // Drawing the line
    Offset startPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    Offset endPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, 0);
    canvas.drawLine(startPoint, endPoint, paint);

    // Drawing the arrowhead
    double arrowSize = 10; // Size of the arrowhead
    double angle = math.pi / 6; // Angle of the arrowhead
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 - arrowSize * math.cos(angle), arrowSize * math.sin(angle));
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + arrowSize * math.cos(angle), arrowSize * math.sin(angle));

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Call the class:

```
CustomPaint(
            size: Size(10, 200), // Width and height of the arrow
            painter: ArrowPainter(),
            )
```